# Mysql get weekly average of daily data

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have a table called primeWeek. Im trying to get weekly avg depends on dates.

Example of my table

```
id | count | date
1  |  70   | 2020-08-29
2  |  67   | 2020-08-30
3  |  69   | 2020-08-31
4  |  82   | 2020-09-01
5  |  73   | 2020-09-02
```

I tried few things but results are not correct.

Comment: What have you tried and what was the result?

Comment: I tried 

SELECT AVG(count) AS primeCount , CONCAT(date, '-', date + INTERVAL 6 DAY) AS week
FROM primeTime
GROUP BY WEEK(date)
ORDER BY WEEK(date)

But the result is not the real avg and there is a date 2020-11-07 at result but not in data

Comment: `count` is a keyword in SQL, so you should surround it with backticks.

Comment: Keywords are not the problem here, your query works fine as is: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=6f2f053a40967373d5dc608832b3d037 (although the resuts may not be exactly what you intend due to a non-aggregated column that is not in the `GROUP BY` clause).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`count` and `date` are both keywords in SQL, so you should surround them with backticks.

```
SELECT
    AVG(`count`) AS primeCount,
    CONCAT(`date`, '-', `date` + INTERVAL 6 DAY) AS week
FROM primeWeek
GROUP BY WEEK(`date`)
ORDER BY WEEK(`date`);
```